# What can we say about $\frac{1}{2(1-z)}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\{n\sqrt{2}\}z^n$ in the vicinity of $z=1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, asymptotics, ergodic-theory

Let $\{x\}$ denote the fractional part of $x$, what can we say about $$\frac{1}{2(1-z)}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\{n\sqrt{2}\}z^n$$ in the vicinity of $z=1$? It seems that there is no limit, but the partial sums seem bounded.

Comment: Not sure : try with unlimited precision $z=\frac {999}{1000}$ and then $z=\frac {9999}{10000}$ for $10000$ summands.

Comment: Dear Claude, I did it of course, and even more. You can plot the curve plot(sum(frac(n*sqrt(2))*x^n, n = 0 .. 5000) - 1/2/(1 - x), x = 0.6 .. 0.99)...to "understand" the phenomena.

Comment: @OlivierBodini what partial sums are you talking about?

Comment: One can show, for $\xi_n := \{n\sqrt{2}\}-\frac{1}{2}$, that $\sum_n \xi_n(1-\epsilon)^n = \sum_{\frac{\epsilon^{-1}}{\log(\epsilon^{-1})} \le n \le \epsilon^{-1}\log(\epsilon^{-1})} \xi_n (1-\epsilon)^n + o_{\epsilon \to 0}(1)$. So we can restrict attention to $\frac{\epsilon^{-1}}{\log(\epsilon^{-1})} \le n \le \epsilon^{-1}\log(\epsilon^{-1})$.